# how to check the command name is "find" and exit prompt before command prompt in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

any can help me?

original

```sh
➜  ~ find
here preexec block...
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

I want do it like this!

```sh
➜  ~ find
here preexec block...
haha!find disable by super manager
➜  ~
```

I tried to use the preexec precmd hook function in zsh.define zshrc

```sh
precmd(){
  # echo 'here precmd block...'
  echo 'here precmd block...'
  if [[ "npm" == "$1" ]];
  then
    echo 'haha 123'
    exit 0
  fi
}

preexec(){
  echo 'here preexec block...'
  if [[ "npm" == "$1" ]];
  then
    echo 'haha 123'
    exit 0
  fi
}
```

But the result is killing the shell.

Comment: Which specific shells are you looking for? both `bash` or in `zsh` or in either one

Comment: Sorry, but I do not undestrand what your question is. Especially the comment in your expect output 'disable by super mamager'. A misuse of a command does not signify that the SU disabled it.

Comment: @Inian I want it to work on Zsh

Comment: @kvantour I updated the question.

Comment: With all do respect, but I do not understand the question at all.

Comment: If you want to disable `find`, you change its permissions; you don't make easily bypassed shell configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of [Use preexec() to evaluate entered command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099966/use-preexec-to-evaluate-entered-command)

The gist is preexec executes in the shell's context (so kills the shell if you exit), and it doesn't provide for altering or cancelling the command being executed, but you should be able to hook into `accept-buffer` to do what you want.

A much simpler option is to simply alias the executable you want to disable to something else:

```
> alias find=echo
> find . -name 'foo'
. -name foo
```

though it will only work on generic lookups, not lookups specifically through /bin/env or the executable's path.